# Getting issue with node-exporter because of PSP (pod security policy)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Im getting this error

```
Error creating: pods "node-exporter" is forbidden: unable to validate against any pod security policy: [spec.secur
ityContext.hostNetwork: Invalid value: true: Host network is not allowed to be used spec.securityContext.hostPID: Invalid value: true: Host PID is not allowed to be used spec.contain
ers[0].hostPort: Invalid value: 9100: Host port 9100 is not allowed to be used. Allowed ports: [0-8000]]
```

But i checked in another cluster in GCP, its not giving me any issue. Does anyone knows why i'm getting this issue

Answer (score 1):

node-exporter needs direct access to the node-level network namespace to be able to gather statistics on this. You have a default security policy that blocks this access. You'll need to make a new policy which allows it, and assign that policy to node-exporter.

Comment: my current pod security policy is the dumb from a working cluster. So i don't understand how you meant by that, creating new policy and assign it to node exporter. Im using this in kubernetes in gcp.

Comment: spec:
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  allowedCapabilities:
  - '*'
  defaultAllowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  fsGroup:
    rule: RunAsAny
  hostPorts:
  - max: 8000
    min: 0
  runAsUser:
    rule: RunAsAny
  seLinux:
    rule: RunAsAny
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: RunAsAny
 
this is my psp file which iam having now

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/wiki/Default-port-allocations) default port for node-exporter is `9100` which is outside of the range `[0 - 8000]` specified by Your Pod security policy. You can see that in the error You provided.

Like coderanger mentioned in his answer. You need to make new policy for the node-exporter.

The simplest way to fix that is to install Prometheus from helm chart which will automatically create `PSP` from the template that can be found [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus/templates/node-exporter-podsecuritypolicy.yaml).

In the other GCP cluster You can try to look for existing `PodSecurityPolicy` that enables the node-exporter to work correctly. Make sure to look in all namespaces `kubectl get psp --all-namespaces`.

Hope it helps.